# CgRectGetWidth monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, cgrect

```
floorf(CGRectGetMinX(visibleBounds) / CGRectGetWidth(visibleBounds));
```

What is the monotouch version of the methods `CGrectGetWidth` and CGrectGetMinX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update Xamarin.iOS Unified API

Xamarin.iOS introduced the [Unified API](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/unified/) which now contains `CGRect` and friends inside `CoreGraphics` namespace.

---

`CGRect` is Mapped to `System.Drawing.RectangleF` ([See Type Mappings](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types#Type_mappings))

So if you have your own `System.Drawing.RectangleF`

The code would look like

```
RectangleF visibleBounds = new RectangleF(0, 0, 10, 10); // Or your own instance of visibleBounds           
float minx = visibleBounds.GetMinX();
float w = visibleBounds.Width;
```

Hope that helps

Alex